# R DTW multivariate series with asymmetric step fails to compute alignment

Tags: python, r

I'm using the DTW implementation found in R along with the python bindings in order to verify the effects of changing different parameters(like local constraint, local distance function and others) for my data. The data represents feature vectors that an audio processing frontend outputs(MFCC). Because of this I am dealing with multivariate time series, each feature vector has a size of 8. The problem I'm facing is when I try to use certain local constraints ( or step patterns ) I get the following error:

```
Error in if (is.na(gcm$distance)) { : argument is of length zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r_dtw_simplified.py", line 32, in <module>
    alignment = R.dtw(canDist, rNull, "Euclidean", stepPattern, "none", True, Fa
lse, True, False )
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 86, in _
_call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 35, in _
_call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in if (is.na(gcm$distance)) { : argument is
 of length zero
```

Because the process of generating and adapting the input data is complicated I only made a simplified script to ilustrate the error i'm receiving.

```
#data works
#reference = [[-0.126678, -1.541763, 0.29985, 1.719757, 0.755798, -3.594681, -1.492798, 3.493042], [-0.110596, -1.638184, 0.128174, 1.638947, 0.721085, -3.247696, -0.920013, 3.763977], [-0.022415, -1.643539, -0.130692, 1.441742, 1.022064, -2.882172, -0.952225, 3.662842], [0.071259, -2.030411, -0.531891, 0.835114, 1.320419, -2.432281, -0.469116, 3.871094], [0.070526, -2.056702, -0.688293, 0.530396, 1.962128, -1.681915, -0.368973, 4.542419], [0.047745, -2.005127, -0.798203, 0.616028, 2.146988, -1.895874, 0.371597, 4.090881], [0.013962, -2.162796, -1.008545, 0.363495, 2.062866, -0.856613, 0.543884, 4.043335], [0.066757, -2.152969, -1.087097, 0.257263, 2.592697, -0.422424, -0.280533, 3.327576], [0.123123, -2.061035, -1.012863, 0.389282, 2.50206, 0.078186, -0.887711, 2.828247], [0.157455, -2.060425, -0.790344, 0.210419, 2.542114, 0.016983, -0.959274, 1.916504], [0.029648, -2.128204, -1.047318, 0.116547, 2.44899, 0.166534, -0.677551, 2.49231], [0.158554, -1.821365, -1.045044, 0.374207, 2.426712, 0.406952, -1.055084, 2.543762], [0.077026, -1.863235, -1.14827, 0.277069, 2.669067, 0.362549, -1.294342, 1.66748], [0.101822, -1.800293, -1.126801, 0.364594, 2.503815, 0.294846, -0.881302, 1.281616], [0.166138, -1.627762, -0.866013, 0.494476, 2.450668, 0.569, -1.392868, 0.651184], [0.225006, -1.596069, -1.07634, 0.550049, 2.167435, 0.554123, -1.432983, 1.166931], [0.114777, -1.462769, -0.793167, 0.565704, 2.183792, 0.345978, -1.410919, 0.708679], [0.144028, -1.444458, -0.831985, 0.536652, 2.222366, 0.330368, -0.715149, 0.517212], [0.147888, -1.450577, -0.809372, 0.479584, 2.271378, 0.250763, -0.540359, -0.036072], [0.090714, -1.485474, -0.888153, 0.268768, 2.001221, 0.412537, -0.698868, 0.17157], [0.11972, -1.382767, -0.890457, 0.218414, 1.666519, 0.659592, -0.069641, 0.914307], [0.189774, -1.18428, -0.785797, 0.106659, 1.429977, 0.195236, 0.627029, 0.503296], [0.194702, -1.098068, -0.956818, 0.020386, 1.369247, 0.10437, 0.641724, 0.410767], [0.215134, -1.069092, -1.11644, 0.283234, 1.313507, 0.110962, 0.600861, 0.752869], [0.216766, -1.065338, -1.047974, 0.080231, 1.500702, -0.113388, 0.712646, 0.914307], [0.259933, -0.964386, -0.981369, 0.092224, 1.480667, -0.00238, 0.896255, 0.665344], [0.265991, -0.935257, -0.93779, 0.214966, 1.235275, 0.104782, 1.33754, 0.599487], [0.266098, -0.62619, -0.905792, 0.131409, 0.402908, 0.103363, 1.352814, 1.554688], [0.273468, -0.354691, -0.709579, 0.228027, 0.315125, -0.15564, 0.942123, 1.024292], [0.246429, -0.272522, -0.609924, 0.318604, -0.007355, -0.165756, 1.07019, 1.087708], [0.248596, -0.232468, -0.524887, 0.53009, -0.476334, -0.184479, 1.088089, 0.667358], [0.074478, -0.200455, -0.058411, 0.662811, -0.111923, -0.686462, 1.205154, 1.271912], [0.063065, -0.080765, 0.065552, 0.79071, -0.569946, -0.899506, 0.875687, 0.095215], [0.117706, -0.270584, -0.021027, 0.723694, -0.200073, -0.365158, 0.892624, -0.152466], [0.00148, -0.075348, 0.017761, 0.757507, 0.719299, -0.355362, 0.749329, 0.315247], [0.035034, -0.110794, 0.038559, 0.949677, 0.478699, 0.005951, 0.097305, -0.388245], [-0.101944, -0.392487, 0.401886, 1.154938, 0.199127, 0.117371, -0.070007, -0.562439], [-0.083282, -0.388657, 0.449066, 1.505951, 0.46405, -0.566208, 0.216293, -0.528076], [-0.152054, -0.100113, 0.833054, 1.746857, 0.085861, -1.314102, 0.294632, -0.470947], [-0.166672, -0.183777, 0.988373, 1.925262, -0.202057, -0.961441, 0.15242, 0.594421], [-0.234573, -0.227707, 1.102112, 1.802002, -0.382492, -1.153336, 0.29335, 0.074036], [-0.336426, 0.042435, 1.255096, 1.804535, -0.610153, -0.810745, 1.308441, 0.599854], [-0.359344, 0.007248, 1.344543, 1.441559, -0.758286, -0.800079, 1.0233, 0.668213], [-0.321823, 0.027618, 1.1521, 1.509827, -0.708267, -0.668152, 1.05722, 0.710571], [-0.265335, 0.012344, 1.491501, 1.844971, -0.584137, -1.042419, -0.449188, 0.5354], [-0.302399, 0.049698, 1.440643, 1.674866, -0.626633, -1.158554, -0.906937, 0.405579], [-0.330276, 0.466675, 1.444153, 0.855499, -0.645447, -0.352158, 0.730423, 0.429932], [-0.354721, 0.540207, 1.570786, 0.626648, -0.897446, -0.007416, 0.174042, 0.100525], [-0.239609, 0.669983, 0.978851, 0.85321, -0.156784, 0.107986, 0.915054, 0.114197], [-0.189346, 0.930756, 0.824295, 0.516083, -0.339767, -0.206314, 0.744049, -0.36377]]
#query = [[0.387268, -1.21701, -0.432266, -1.394104, -0.458984, -1.469788, 0.12764, 2.310059], [0.418091, -1.389526, -0.150146, -0.759155, -0.578003, -2.123199, 0.276001, 3.022339], [0.264694, -1.526886, -0.238907, -0.511108, -0.90683, -2.699249, 0.692032, 2.849854], [0.246628, -1.675171, -0.533432, 0.070007, -0.392151, -1.739227, 0.534485, 2.744019], [0.099335, -1.983826, -0.985291, 0.428833, 0.26535, -1.285583, -0.234451, 2.4729], [0.055893, -2.108063, -0.401825, 0.860413, 0.724106, -1.959137, -1.360458, 2.350708], [-0.131592, -1.928314, -0.056213, 0.577698, 0.859146, -1.812286, -1.21669, 2.2052], [-0.162796, -2.149933, 0.467239, 0.524231, 0.74913, -1.829498, -0.741913, 1.616577], [-0.282745, -1.971008, 0.837616, 0.56427, 0.198288, -1.826935, -0.118027, 1.599731], [-0.497223, -1.578705, 1.277298, 0.682983, 0.055084, -2.032562, 0.64151, 1.719238], [-0.634232, -1.433258, 1.760513, 0.550415, -0.053787, -2.188568, 1.666687, 1.611938], [-0.607498, -1.302826, 1.960556, 1.331726, 0.417633, -2.271973, 2.095001, 0.9823], [-0.952957, -0.222076, 0.772064, 2.062256, -0.295258, -1.255371, 3.450974, -0.047607], [-1.210587, 1.00061, 0.036392, 1.952209, 0.470123, 0.231628, 2.670502, -0.608276], [-1.213287, 0.927002, -0.414825, 2.104065, 1.160126, 0.088898, 1.32959, -0.018311], [-1.081558, 1.007751, -0.337509, 1.7146, 0.653687, 0.297089, 1.916733, -0.772461], [-1.064804, 1.284302, -0.393585, 2.150635, 0.132294, 0.443298, 1.967575, 0.775513], [-0.972366, 1.039734, -0.588135, 1.413818, 0.423813, 0.781494, 1.977509, -0.556274], [-0.556381, 0.591309, -0.678314, 1.025635, 1.094284, 2.234711, 1.504013, -1.71875], [-0.063477, 0.626129, 0.360489, 0.149902, 0.92804, 0.936493, 1.203018, 0.264282], [0.162003, 0.577698, 0.956863, -0.477051, 1.081161, 0.817749, 0.660843, -0.428711], [-0.049515, 0.423615, 0.82489, 0.446228, 1.323853, 0.562775, -0.144196, 1.145386], [-0.146851, 0.171906, 0.304871, 0.320435, 1.378937, 0.673004, 0.188416, 0.208618], [0.33992, -2.072418, -0.447968, 0.526794, -0.175858, -1.400299, -0.452454, 1.396606], [0.226089, -2.183441, -0.301071, -0.475159, 0.834961, -2.191864, -1.092361, 2.434814], [0.279556, -2.073181, -0.517639, -0.766479, 0.974808, -2.070374, -2.003891, 2.706421], [0.237961, -1.9245, -0.708435, -0.582153, 1.285934, -1.75882, -2.146164, 2.369995], [0.149658, -1.703705, -0.539749, -0.215332, 1.369705, -1.484802, -1.506256, 1.04126], [0.078735, -1.719543, 0.157013, 0.382385, 1.100998, -0.223755, 0.021683, -0.545654], [0.106003, -1.404358, 0.372345, 1.881165, -0.292511, -0.263855, 1.579529, -1.426025], [0.047729, -1.198608, 0.600769, 1.901123, -1.106949, 0.128815, 1.293701, -1.364258], [0.110748, -0.894348, 0.712601, 1.728699, -1.250381, 0.674377, 0.812302, -1.428833], [0.085754, -0.662903, 0.794312, 1.102844, -1.234283, 1.084442, 0.986938, -1.10022], [0.140823, -0.300323, 0.673508, 0.669983, -0.551453, 1.213074, 1.449326, -1.567261], [0.03743, 0.550293, 0.400909, -0.174622, 0.355301, 1.325867, 0.875854, 0.126953], [-0.084885, 1.128906, 0.292099, -0.248779, 0.722961, 0.873871, -0.409515, 0.470581], [0.019684, 0.947754, 0.19931, -0.306274, 0.176849, 1.431702, 1.091507, 0.701416], [-0.094162, 0.895203, 0.687378, -0.229065, 0.549088, 1.376953, 0.892303, -0.642334], [-0.727692, 0.626495, 0.848877, 0.521362, 1.521912, -0.443481, 1.247238, 0.197388], [-0.82048, 0.117279, 0.975174, 1.487244, 1.085281, -0.567993, 0.776093, -0.381592], [-0.009827, -0.553009, -0.213135, 0.837341, 0.482712, -0.939423, 0.140884, 0.330566], [-0.018127, -1.362335, -0.199265, 1.260742, 0.005188, -1.445068, -1.159653, 1.220825], [0.186172, -1.727814, -0.246552, 1.544128, 0.285416, 0.081848, -1.634003, -0.47522], [0.193649, -1.144043, -0.334854, 1.220276, 1.241302, 1.554382, 0.57048, -1.334961], [0.344604, -1.647461, -0.720749, 0.993774, 0.585709, 0.953522, -0.493042, -1.845703], [0.37471, -1.989471, -0.518555, 0.555908, -0.025787, 0.148132, -1.463425, -0.844849], [0.34523, -1.821625, -0.809418, 0.59137, -0.577927, 0.037903, -2.067764, -0.519531], [0.413193, -1.503876, -0.752243, 0.280396, -0.236206, 0.429932, -1.684097, -0.724731], [0.331299, -1.349243, -0.890121, -0.178589, -0.285721, 0.809875, -2.012329, -0.157227], [0.278946, -1.090057, -0.670441, -0.477539, -0.267105, 0.446045, -1.95668, 0.501343], [0.127304, -0.977112, -0.660324, -1.011658, -0.547409, 0.349182, -1.357574, 1.045654], [0.217728, -0.793182, -0.496262, -1.259949, -0.128937, 0.38855, -1.513306, 1.863647], [0.240143, -0.891541, -0.619995, -1.478577, -0.361481, 0.258362, -1.630585, 1.841064], [0.241547, -0.758453, -0.515442, -1.370605, -0.428238, 0.23996, -1.469406, 1.307617], [0.289948, -0.714661, -0.533798, -1.574036, 0.017929, -0.368317, -1.290283, 0.851563], [0.304916, -0.783752, -0.459915, -1.523621, -0.107651, -0.027649, -1.089905, 0.969238], [0.27179, -0.795593, -0.352432, -1.597656, -0.001678, -0.06189, -1.072495, 0.637329], [0.301956, -0.823578, -0.152115, -1.637634, 0.2034, -0.214508, -1.315491, 0.773071], [0.282486, -0.853271, -0.162094, -1.561096, 0.15686, -0.289307, -1.076874, 0.673706], [0.299881, -0.97052, -0.051086, -1.431152, -0.074692, -0.32428, -1.385452, 0.684326], [0.220886, -1.072266, -0.269531, -1.038269, 0.140533, -0.711273, -1.7453, 1.090332], [0.177628, -1.229126, -0.274292, -0.943481, 0.483246, -1.214447, -2.026321, 0.719971], [0.176987, -1.137543, -0.007645, -0.794861, 0.965118, -1.084717, -2.37677, 0.598267], [0.135727, -1.36795, 0.09462, -0.776367, 0.946655, -1.157959, -2.794403, 0.226074], [0.067337, -1.648987, 0.535721, -0.665833, 1.506119, -1.348755, -3.092728, 0.281616], [-0.038101, -1.437347, 0.983917, -0.280762, 1.880722, -1.351318, -3.002258, -0.599609], [-0.152573, -1.146027, 0.717545, -0.60321, 2.126541, -0.59198, -2.282028, -1.048584], [-0.113525, -0.629669, 0.925323, 0.465393, 2.368698, -0.352661, -1.969391, -0.915161], [-0.140121, -0.311951, 0.884262, 0.809021, 1.557693, -0.552429, -1.776062, -0.925537], [-0.189423, -0.117767, 0.975174, 1.595032, 1.284485, -0.698639, -2.007202, -1.307251], [-0.048874, -0.176941, 0.820679, 1.306519, 0.584259, -0.913147, -0.658066, -0.630981], [-0.127594, 0.33313, 0.791336, 1.400696, 0.685577, -1.500275, -0.657959, -0.207642], [-0.044128, 0.653351, 0.615326, 0.476685, 1.099625, -0.902893, -0.154449, 0.325073], [-0.150223, 1.059845, 1.208405, -0.038635, 0.758667, 0.458038, -0.178909, -0.998657], [-0.099854, 1.127197, 0.789871, -0.013611, 0.452805, 0.736176, 0.948273, -0.236328], [-0.250275, 1.188568, 0.935989, 0.34314, 0.130463, 0.879913, 1.669037, 0.12793], [-0.122818, 1.441223, 0.670029, 0.389526, -0.15274, 1.293549, 1.22908, -1.132568]]

#this one doesn't
reference = [[-0.453598, -2.439209, 0.973587, 1.362091, -0.073654, -1.755112, 1.090057, 4.246765], [-0.448502, -2.621201, 0.723282, 1.257324, 0.26619, -1.375351, 1.328735, 4.46991], [-0.481247, -2.29718, 0.612854, 1.078033, 0.309708, -2.037506, 1.056305, 3.181702], [-0.42482, -2.306702, 0.436157, 1.529907, 0.50708, -1.930069, 0.653198, 3.561768], [-0.39032, -2.361343, 0.589294, 1.965607, 0.611801, -2.417084, 0.035675, 3.381104], [-0.233444, -2.281525, 0.703171, 2.17868, 0.519257, -2.474442, -0.502808, 3.569153], [-0.174652, -1.924591, 0.180267, 2.127075, 0.250626, -2.208527, -0.396591, 2.565552], [-0.121078, -1.53801, 0.234344, 2.221039, 0.845367, -1.516205, -0.174149, 1.298645], [-0.18631, -1.047806, 0.629654, 2.073303, 0.775024, -1.931076, 0.382706, 2.278442], [-0.160477, -0.78743, 0.694214, 1.917572, 0.834885, -1.574707, 0.780045, 2.370422], [-0.203659, -0.427246, 0.726486, 1.548767, 0.465698, -1.185379, 0.555206, 2.619629], [-0.208298, -0.393707, 0.771881, 1.646484, 0.612946, -0.996277, 0.658539, 2.499146], [-0.180679, -0.166656, 0.689209, 1.205994, 0.3918, -1.051483, 0.771072, 1.854553], [-0.1978, 0.082764, 0.723541, 1.019104, 0.165405, -0.127533, 1.0522, 0.552368], [-0.171127, 0.168533, 0.529541, 0.584839, 0.702011, -0.36525, 0.711792, 1.029114], [-0.224243, 0.38765, 0.916031, 0.45108, 0.708923, -0.059326, 1.016312, 0.437561], [-0.217072, -0.981766, 1.67363, 1.864014, 0.050812, -2.572815, -0.22937, 0.757996], [-0.284714, -0.784927, 1.720383, 1.782379, -0.093414, -2.492111, 0.623398, 0.629028], [-0.261169, -0.427979, 1.680038, 1.585358, 0.067093, -1.8181, 1.276291, 0.838989], [-0.183075, -0.08197, 1.094147, 1.120392, -0.117752, -0.86142, 1.94194, 0.966858], [-0.188919, 0.121521, 1.277664, 0.90979, 0.114288, -0.880875, 1.920517, 0.95752], [-0.226868, 0.338455, 0.78067, 0.803009, 0.347092, -0.387955, 0.641296, 0.374634], [-0.206329, 0.768158, 0.759537, 0.264099, 0.15979, 0.152618, 0.911636, -0.011597], [-0.230453, 0.495941, 0.547165, 0.137604, 0.36377, 0.594406, 1.168839, 0.125916], [0.340851, -0.382736, -1.060455, -0.267792, 1.1306, 0.595047, -1.544922, -1.6828], [0.341492, -0.325836, -1.07164, -0.215607, 0.895645, 0.400177, -0.773956, -1.827515], [0.392075, -0.305389, -0.885422, -0.293427, 0.993225, 0.66655, -1.061218, -1.730713], [0.30191, -0.339005, -0.877853, 0.153992, 0.986588, 0.711823, -1.100525, -1.648376], [0.303574, -0.491241, -1.000183, 0.075378, 0.686295, 0.752792, -1.192123, -1.744568], [0.315781, -0.629456, -0.996063, 0.224731, 1.074173, 0.757736, -1.170807, -2.08313], [0.313675, -0.804688, -1.00325, 0.431641, 0.685883, 0.538879, -0.988373, -2.421326], [0.267181, -0.790329, -0.726974, 0.853027, 1.369629, -0.213638, -1.708023, -1.977844], [0.304459, -0.935257, -0.778061, 1.042633, 1.391861, -0.296768, -1.562164, -2.014099], [0.169754, -0.792953, -0.481842, 1.404236, 0.766983, -0.29805, -1.587265, -1.25531], [0.15918, -0.9814, -0.197662, 1.748718, 0.888367, -0.880234, -1.64949, -1.359802], [0.028244, -0.772934, -0.186172, 1.594238, 0.863571, -1.224701, -1.153183, -0.292664], [-0.020401, -0.461578, 0.368088, 1.000366, 1.079636, -0.389603, -0.144409, 0.651733], [0.018555, -0.725418, 0.632599, 1.707336, 0.535049, -1.783859, -0.916122, 1.557007], [-0.038971, -0.797668, 0.820419, 1.483093, 0.350494, -1.465073, -0.786453, 1.370361], [-0.244888, -0.469513, 1.067978, 1.028809, 0.4879, -1.796585, -0.77887, 1.888977], [-0.260193, -0.226593, 1.141754, 1.21228, 0.214005, -1.200943, -0.441177, 0.532715], [-0.165283, 0.016129, 1.263016, 0.745514, -0.211288, -0.802368, 0.215698, 0.316406], [-0.353134, 0.053787, 1.544189, 0.21106, -0.469086, -0.485367, 0.767761, 0.849548], [-0.330215, 0.162704, 1.570053, 0.304718, -0.561172, -0.410294, 0.895126, 0.858093], [-0.333847, 0.173904, 1.56958, 0.075531, -0.5569, -0.259552, 1.276764, 0.749084], [-0.347107, 0.206665, 1.389832, 0.50473, -0.721664, -0.56955, 1.542618, 0.817444], [-0.299057, 0.140244, 1.402924, 0.215363, -0.62767, -0.550461, 1.60788, 0.506958], [-0.292084, 0.052063, 1.463348, 0.290497, -0.462875, -0.497452, 1.280609, 0.261841], [-0.279877, 0.183548, 1.308609, 0.305756, -0.6483, -0.374771, 1.647781, 0.161865], [-0.28389, 0.27916, 1.148636, 0.466736, -0.724442, -0.21991, 1.819901, -0.218872], [-0.275528, 0.309753, 1.192856, 0.398163, -0.828781, -0.268066, 1.763672, 0.116089], [-0.275284, 0.160019, 1.200623, 0.718628, -0.925552, -0.026596, 1.367447, 0.174866], [-0.302795, 0.383438, 1.10556, 0.441833, -0.968323, -0.137375, 1.851791, 0.357971], [-0.317078, 0.22876, 1.272217, 0.462219, -0.855789, -0.294296, 1.593994, 0.127502], [-0.304932, 0.207718, 1.156189, 0.481506, -0.866776, -0.340027, 1.670105, 0.657837], [-0.257217, 0.155655, 1.041428, 0.717926, -0.761597, -0.17244, 1.114151, 0.653503], [-0.321426, 0.292358, 0.73848, 0.422607, -0.850754, -0.057907, 1.462357, 0.697754], [-0.34642, 0.361526, 0.69722, 0.585175, -0.464508, -0.26651, 1.860596, 0.106201], [-0.339844, 0.584229, 0.542603, 0.184937, -0.341263, 0.085648, 1.837311, 0.160461], [-0.32338, 0.661224, 0.512833, 0.319702, -0.195572, 0.004028, 1.046799, 0.233704], [-0.346329, 0.572388, 0.385986, 0.118988, 0.057556, 0.039001, 1.255081, -0.18573], [-0.383392, 0.558395, 0.553391, -0.358612, 0.443573, -0.086014, 0.652878, 0.829956], [-0.420395, 0.668991, 0.64856, -0.021271, 0.511475, 0.639221, 0.860474, 0.463196], [-0.359039, 0.748672, 0.522964, -0.308899, 0.717194, 0.218811, 0.681396, 0.606812], [-0.323914, 0.942627, 0.249069, -0.418365, 0.673599, 0.797974, 0.162674, 0.120361], [-0.411301, 0.92775, 0.493332, -0.286346, 0.165054, 0.63446, 1.085571, 0.120789], [-0.346191, 0.632309, 0.635056, -0.402496, 0.143814, 0.785614, 0.952164, 0.482727], [-0.203812, 0.789261, 0.240433, -0.47699, -0.12912, 0.91832, 1.145493, 0.052002], [-0.048203, 0.632095, 0.009583, -0.53833, 0.232727, 1.293045, 0.308151, 0.188904], [-0.062393, 0.732315, 0.06694, -0.697144, 0.126221, 0.864578, 0.581635, -0.088379]]
query = [[-0.113144, -3.316223, -1.101563, -2.128418, 1.853867, 3.61972, 1.218185, 1.71228], [-0.128952, -3.37915, -1.152237, -2.033081, 1.860199, 4.008179, 0.445938, 1.665894], [-0.0392, -2.976654, -0.888245, -1.613953, 1.638641, 3.849518, 0.034073, 0.768188], [-0.146042, -2.980713, -1.044113, -1.44397, 0.954514, 3.20929, -0.232422, 1.050781], [-0.155029, -2.997192, -1.064438, -1.369873, 0.67688, 2.570709, -0.855347, 1.523438], [-0.102341, -2.686401, -1.029648, -1.00531, 0.950089, 1.933228, -0.526367, 1.598633], [-0.060272, -2.538727, -1.278259, -0.65332, 0.630875, 1.459717, -0.264038, 1.872925], [0.064087, -2.592682, -1.112823, -0.775024, 0.848618, 0.810883, 0.298965, 2.312134], [0.111557, -2.815277, -1.203506, -1.173584, 0.54863, 0.46756, -0.023071, 3.029053], [0.266068, -2.624786, -1.089066, -0.864136, 0.055389, 0.619446, -0.160965, 2.928589], [0.181488, -2.31073, -1.307785, -0.720276, 0.001297, 0.534668, 0.495499, 2.989502], [0.216202, -2.25354, -1.288193, -0.902039, -0.152283, -0.060791, 0.566315, 2.911621], [0.430084, -2.0289, -1.099594, -1.091736, -0.302505, -0.087799, 0.955963, 2.677002], [0.484253, -1.412842, -0.881882, -1.087158, -1.064072, -0.145935, 1.437683, 2.606567], [0.339081, -1.277222, -1.24498, -1.048279, -0.219498, 0.448517, 1.168625, 0.563843], [0.105728, 0.138275, -1.01413, -0.489868, 1.319275, 1.604645, 1.634003, -0.94812], [-0.209061, 1.025665, 0.180405, 0.955566, 1.527405, 0.91745, 1.951233, -0.40686], [-0.136993, 1.332275, 0.639862, 1.277832, 1.277313, 0.361267, 0.390717, -0.728394], [-0.217758, 1.416718, 1.080002, 0.816101, 0.343933, -0.154175, 1.10347, -0.568848]]


reference = np.array( reference )
query = np.array( query )
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
# Set up our R namespaces
R = rpy2.robjects.r
rNull = R("NULL")
rprint = rpy2.robjects.globalenv.get("print")
rplot = rpy2.robjects.r('plot')
distConstr = rpy2.robjects.r('proxy::dist')
DTW = importr('dtw')
stepName = "asymmetricP05"
stepPattern = rpy2.robjects.r( stepName )
canDist = distConstr( reference, query, "Euclidean" ) #
alignment = R.dtw(canDist, rNull, "Euclidean", stepPattern, "none", True, False, True, False )
```

For some series the script doesn't generate the error but there are some which do. See the commented lines for examples. It is worth noting that for the classic constraint this error does not appear. I am thinking that perhaps I have not set-up something correct but  I am no expert in python nor in R so that is why I was hoping that others who have used the R DTW can help me on this. I am sorry for the long lines for reference and query (the data is from outputting the MFCC's of a 2 second wav file).

Answer (score 0):

One of the two series is too short to be compatible with the fancy step pattern you chose. Use the common `symmetric2` pattern, which does not restrict slopes, before the more exotic ones.